# Windows server 2016: Instances monitoring

Tags: sql-server, windows, server, analytics, windows-server-2016

I have very general question, we are a bunch of analytical consultants. We use same server with multiple instances. Is there a way I can track which instance is opened by which desktop user?

Thanks for your time.

This is what I see on my taskManager:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way I could know the desktop username, who is on which instance. Please let me know the workaround. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you are refer to user instance that connect to a same server via RDP

you can check user session information on task manager > user tab

[image]

if you are refer to which process instance is run by which users

then you can go to task manager > Details tab

Comment: But how will I get the desktop username? Sorry, I am not satisfied with this answer.

Comment: the "user" column or "user name" column which under the task manager tab tell the windows user account name. If multiple of your users is sharing a same windows login account ( let say “administrator” account) , then you won’t able differential it and you have to create multiple windows user account and each windows user account map to one unique user , finally give them the login info  and you can track them via task manager . (remember reset your shared account password so that they no longer able login using old shared account)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked server for all of your instances and call a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'INSTANCE 1', loginame, hostname, dbname
from openquery(LINKEDSERVER1,'EXEC sp_who;')
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'INSTANCE 2', loginame, hostname, dbname
from openquery(LINKEDSERVER2,'EXEC sp_who;')
```

For more information about how to create a linked server, please check https://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server